# onmouseover alternative for mobile

Tags: css, mouseevent, mouseover

I need to find a good alternative for the image on the right on [my website](http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/intime2.html) . As you can see, it is an image map with mouse-over event. I need to replicate the same effect on mobile, but obviously on mobile I can't use the `onmouseover` event.

If you check it on mobile it works, but you need to keep the picture "touched" to see the effect.

```
 <div class="clock">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" src="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png" border="0" width="434" height="420" orgWidth="434" orgHeight="420" usemap="#image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428">
<area shape="rect" coords="432,418,434,420" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_60334" />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="18,295,124,405,167,310,125,258" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="21,136,19,286,111,245,120,180" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="23,124,135,20,179,124,128,170" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="144,17,298,19,256,123,183,123" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="306,23,413,136,310,178,261,128" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="414,299,416,142,310,182,312,253" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website6.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/6.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="296,413,413,305,309,258,255,307" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
</map>
    <p style=" margin-top: 20px; color: #000;" align="left">Ablauf eines Störfalls in einer Käserei –<br>Wir sind “in Time”.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), particularly `touchstart` and `touchend`.